# change font style in Latexpreview in org mode

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex, overlays, inline-image

The latexpreview image is very poor. I increased the font size but it is still not good. I want to make the writings in the image *bold* or use a better font. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to tell us a lot more about how you produced the image. In particular, the version of Org mode (`M-x org-version` will tell you), the value of  the variable `org-preview-latex-default-process` (`C-h v org-preview-latex-default-process RET` will tell you that) and the value of the variable `org-preview-latex-process-alist` (`C-h v` again, but with this variable). Edit your question and add this information.

Comment: org version 9. The process is divping.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Have you tried other processes? I use `imagemagick` and I have had no problems. Also, you can run the command lines for `dvipng` in a shell, outside of Org mode's latex preview. It may be that the problem is something like a missing font: it's much easier to debug these things when you run each command explicitly; Org mode tends to hide things, which is great when everything is working, but not so good when you are trying to debug.

Comment: You should add the information to the question: comments can disappear at any time. The question should stand on its own, without depending on comments to complete it. Without the additional information, the question might be closed. One additional thing you might want to post is the example you used: both the latex code that you used in the Org mode file and maybe an image of the resulting png. If the code was in the question, people could try it out in their setups and you'd be more likely to get an answer to your question.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.